# How to hide save order button in woocommerce edit orders?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to hide save order button from admin in woocommerce edit orders if specific role is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Orders menu is protected by ‘edit_shop_orders’ capability. It’s possible to prohibit new order creation if you activate ‘create’ capability at User Role Editor Settings.

But ‘edit_shop_orders’ capability is enough to ‘process’ and ‘complete’ the order. The only way to allow a read-only access to the WooCommerce orders is to use this filter from WooCommerce code:

```
$actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', $actions, $the_order );
```

Your function for this filter should return empty $actions array for ‘editor’ role in order to make for them read-only access.

### Let me know if you need further help.

Add This piece of code to function which gets executed ONLY for "specific" role:

```
function add_my_action($actions, $the_order){

    return array();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_my_action', 10, 2);**
```

Comment: i want to hide save order button for specific role, this role can only view order but cannot update orders

Comment: Your function for this filter should return empty $actions array for ‘editor’ role in order to make for them read-only access.

Comment: can you tell me how to hide for custom role?

Comment: Added explanation in answer.